# Angular - How do I save string return from POST?

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm trying to save a string value returned from HTTP POST but it keep being undefined.

My Service:

```
getString(id: string): Observable<any>{
    const params = {
        Id: id
    }
    return this.http.post(url , null, {params:params});
}
```

And the POST will return me some random string

> dsfsdfsdfsfsadfsdfsdafwrewrtwerctwertwerctwertwetrxwet

And in my component:

```
string1: any;
saveString() {
this.transactionService.getString(this.id).subscribe(data => 
{
        this.string1= data;
    })
}
```

But my `string1` and `data` return undefined, the HTTP service successful return the string value. How do I save the value ?

Comment: getString(id: string): Observable<any>{
    const params = {
        Id: id
    }
    return this.http.post(url , null, {params:params}).map(resp=>resp.json());
}


string1: any;
saveString() {
this.transactionService.getString(this.id).subscribe(data => 
{
        this.string1= data;
})
}

Answer (score 0):

Try This set data in subscribe to any

```
string1: any;
saveString() {
    this.transactionService.getString(this.id).subscribe((data:any) => 
    {
        this.string1= data;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wrong with your code.
POST need pass data in second parameter, see doc in https://angular.io/guide/http,

```
/** POST: add a new hero to the database */
addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
  return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('addHero', hero))
    );
}
```